# Javascript array store each value in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I store each value of javascript array in variable such that I can use it to perform further actions?

Eg:

```
var plan = [100, 200];
var months = [3, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < plan.length; i++) {
    p_det = plan[i];
}
for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    m_det = months[i];
}
console.log(p_det * m_det); //Gives me value of 200*6
```

Mathematical action I've to perform such that ((100 * 3) + (200 * 6))

Is storing each value in variable will help?  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can you not do `var result = 0; for (var i = 0; i<plan.length; i++){
 result += plan[i] * months[i];
} console.log(result)`

Comment: How can I multiple index of each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing each element in a variable won't help, you already can access those values using the array[index]. Assuming your arrays are the same length, you can calculate what you want in a loop:

```
for (var sum = 0, i = 0; i < plan.length; i++) {
    sum += plan[i]*month[i];
}
console.log( sum );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) assuming that both arrays have same length

```js
var plan = [100, 200];
var months = [3, 6];

var sum = plan.reduce(function(sum, val, index) {
  return sum + months[index] * val;
}, 0);

snippet.log(sum)
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `while` loop will do. It works for any length, because of the `Math.min()` method for the length.

```js
function s(a, b) {
    var i = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
        r = 0;
    while (i--) {
        r += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return r;
}

document.write(s([100, 200], [3, 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
sum(plan.map((e, i) => e * months[i])
```

where sum is

```
function sum(a) { return a.reduce((x, y) => x + y); }
```